# HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad request urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am beginner to python. I am the developer of Easy APIs Project (http://gcdc2013-easyapisproject.appspot.com) and was doing a Python implementation of weather API using my project. Visit http://gcdc2013-easyapisproject.appspot.com/APIs_Doc.html to see Weather API. The below is my implementation but it returns `HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad request` error.

```
import urllib2

def celsius(a):
    responsex = urllib2.urlopen('http://gcdc2013-easyapisproject.appspot.com/unitconversion?q='+a+' in celsius')
    htmlx = responsex.read()
    responsex.close()
    htmlx = html[1:] #remove first {
    htmlx = html[:-1] #remove last }
    htmlx = html.split('}{') #split and put each resutls to array
    return str(htmlx[1]);

print "Enter a city name:",
q = raw_input() #get word from user
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://gcdc2013-easyapisproject.appspot.com/weather?q='+q)
html = response.read()
response.close()
html = html[1:] #remove first {
html = html[:-1] #remove last }
html = html.split('}{') #split and put each resutls to array
print "Today weather is " + html[1]
print "Temperature is " + html[3]
print "Temperature is " + celsius(html[3])
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string should be quoted using [`urllib.quote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) or [`urllib.quote_plus`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

def celsius(a):
    responsex = urllib2.urlopen('http://gcdc2013-easyapisproject.appspot.com/unitconversion?q=' + urllib.quote(a + ' in celsius'))
    html = responsex.read()
    responsex.close()
    html = html[1:] #remove first {
    html = html[:-1] #remove last }
    html = html.split('}{') #split and put each resutls to array
    return html[0]

print "Enter a city name:",
q = raw_input() #get word from user
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://gcdc2013-easyapisproject.appspot.com/weather?q='+urllib.quote(q))
html = response.read()
print repr(html)
response.close()
html = html[1:] #remove first {
html = html[:-1] #remove last }
html = html.split('}{') #split and put each resutls to array
print "Today weather is " + html[1]
print "Temperature is " + html[3]
print "Temperature is " + celsius(html[3].split()[0])
```

In addition to that, I modified `celsius` to use `html` instead of `htmlx`. The original code mixed use of `html` and `htmlx`.

Comment: Why not use urllib2.quote?

Comment: @selllikesybok, `urllib2.quote` is a reference to `urllib.quote`. Try `import urllib, urllib2; assert urllib2.quote is urllib.quote`.

Comment: Yes, so why import both explicitly? More potential for confusion.

Comment: @selllikesybok, See [`urllib2` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). There's no `quote` function. Using `urllib2.quote` is depending on implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The query should be quoted with `urllib2.quote(q)`

Comment: Actually, the whole part after q?needs to be quoted.